# Booting from shared root over network?

Tags: linux, boot, network-shares, home-networking

I have multiple systems in my home network that are running Linux Mint. I also have a NAS server hooked to the home network, which already serves the various user's home directories (so no matter which machine you use, you always have "your" home directory available).

I also have a Raspberry Pi, which I successfully made to boot its root filesystem from the NAS instead of the SD card.

That latter experience made me wonder, **if it would be possible to have the multiple Linux Mint machines share a common root installation on the network?** I.e., install Linux *to a NAS server share*, then net-booting that installation from my various machines. I've done this for *one* machine already (the Pi), and am wondering if such an installation could be *shared*, so I would have to administrate / update only that one installation.

I see several problems, from `/etc/hostname` over `/dev` to potential concurrency issues, and wonder if this *can* be done, if it has be done before, issues I should be aware of (like, which system directories should *not* be shared but reside on local mounts), and if there might even be some how-to / caveats articles available on the web.

Things I found myself were mostly concerned with single system netboots, cluster systems, or enterprise Windows setups, which is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has apparently [been tried before](http://www.debian-administration.org/users/endecotp/weblog/3) - unsuccessfully.

I still hope somebody else comes up with better news.